# Upload R package to local repository

Tags: r, repository, cran

Is there any R method or function for uploading a personal R package to CRAN local repository?

I think if you move your tar.gz, or your compiled code (windows) to appropiate directory /bin/windows or /src/contrib it would work.

But, is there any function already done for that? Any "upload" function? I have read CRAN doc and google but I have not found a solution.

If I go to IP_LOCAL_REPO:PORT and click on "web form" for submitting packages, these packages are uploaded to my local?

Thanks!

Comment: Someone who has achieved it? The "web form" is not the way for uploading to local repository...

Comment: Ok, someone of R has told me that put R package manually to src/contrib folder and then use tools::write_PACKAGES() to create the index files needed is the best option